# Class of the UI Control ZOOM in HERE MAPS

Tags: javascript, here-api

When placing the ZOOm control e.g. on the top right corner, the the "+" and "-" are side by side. But what if I want to have them on the top of each other? I made a 'bad' code which works:

```
$(".H_l_anchor.H_l_horizontal").each(function(index) {          
    if($(this).html().length>0) {
        if($(this).html().indexOf("H_ctl H_el H_zoom H_grp")>0) {
            $(this).removeClass("H_l_anchor H_l_horizontal").addClass("H_l_anchor H_l_vertical"); 
        }
    }
});
```

But: is there an elegant way?

Answer (score 1):

The Maps API supports changing the position of the UI controls. In the following example, all map controls are moved to the top-left corner of the map viewport.

The code extends the previous example by obtaining an instance of each of the default UI controls and then setting alignment on the controls to the top-left corner.

```
var mapSettings = ui.getControl('mapsettings');
var zoom = ui.getControl('zoom');
var scalebar = ui.getControl('scalebar');

mapSettings.setAlignment('top-left');
zoom.setAlignment('top-left');
scalebar.setAlignment('top-left');
```

Please refer setAlignment more options : https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/api_reference/H.ui.Control.html#setAlignment

Find detail in reference to control alignment : 
https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/dev_guide/topics/map-controls-ui.html

Comment: but how do you change the default look of the zoom controls? If I want to change the `H_Btn` class, what's the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between `LEFT_TOP` and `TOP_LEFT` alignments. Here you can see alignments explained: https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.12.0/api_reference/H.ui.Control.html#setAlignment

What you want is `LEFT_TOP`, so:

```js
ui.getControl('zoom').setAlignment(H.ui.LayoutAlignment.LEFT_TOP);
```

**Note**: You should not specify parameter as simple string e.g.: 'left-top'. It's not safe.